# Replicate columns of a table in two other tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a `table A`, which has the columns:

```
cat
rat
dog
pig
```

I need to paste/replicate this columns in `table B` and `table C`.

But I don't want to create two `INSERT INTO` queries.

I saw using `INNER JOIN` to join two tables in one, but not the other way (that I want).
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Sample data with expected result and table structure witha clear point wise explanation of the logic would be helpful

Comment: @GA1l . . . SQLite (like most databases) only allows you to insert into one table at a time.  I'm not so sure what is so complicated about two `insert into` statements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because this columns that I show is just a example, the real table has A LOT OF columns, so I really wanted to know if I put two tables after `INSERT INTO` will work. It's the same columns, like a backup: Original data in A, and the "backups" in B and C.